# Snowflake + sqlalchemy autoincrement failure

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting the error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column type DECIMAL(38, 0) on column 'id' is not compatible with autoincrement=True`

When using the official example on the Snowflake website (https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#auto-increment-behavior):

`Column('id', Integer, Sequence('id_seq'), primary_key=True)`

Any idea what the correct way is?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. It works when you create a table as in the documentation and then do an insert using the same MetaData object, but it fails when you fetch the table into new metadata. I'll opened an [issue](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/124) for this in their repo.

A workaround is explicitly getting and putting the sequence's next value:

```
seq = Sequence('id_seq')
nextid = connection.execute(seq)
connection.execute(t2.insert(), [ {'id': nextid, 'data': 'test_insert'}])
```